# Web component Vue 2 to Vue 3 Migration

Tags: vuejs3, web-component, custom-tags

We have web component which was created in Vue 2 with @vue/web-component-wrapper. This library is deprecated now. As Vue 2 support will be ending by 31st December. Is there a way to create web component with Vue 3.

To replace this @vue/web-component-wrapper library, Is there anyone has used. Also vue-cli

vue-cli-service --target wc support is also not there. Does anyone has solved this problem ?

Comment: does this *[documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/web-components)* help

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, gone through this documentation but was not able to clearly implement it. I was looking forward for any example for this.

Comment: there's examples in that link isn't there?